# Cannot get JIT to output information when setting DOTNET_JitDump

Tags: .net-core, ryujit

I am trying to analyse why RyuJIT is not inlining some of my C# automatic properties.
I am using JetBrains Trace on Release build to review performance.
I have been trying to follow: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/viewing-jit-dumps.md

Setting the environment variable DOTNET_JitDump (or COMPLUS_JitDump) has no effect, I also tried the registry key alternative. (I copied the example project so set env variable as: DOTNET_JitDump=Main)

I downloaded the latest nightly build to a C:\dotnet folder and tried to get it to use that version, which sort of worked after playing with my Path and registry settings, but dotnet restore would not pickup the right versions for the new runtimes. So abandoned it after spending all day and tried to get it to work on my regular .Net 8 install.

I presume I have misunderstood how this is supposed to work.
Also, after setting  DOTNET_PerfMapEnabled=2 I thought I would get a JITDump but I cannot find any such file. Does anyone know the expected location?